# GeddyJS (Node.js+Socket.io framework) realtime option

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, geddy

I have a Geddy app that has some realtime models (I remember using -rt to generate some models), and I'd like to revisit the realtime-ness of my Geddy app.

I don't need my models to be updated automatically (I'm not sharing models with the client; I am using Geddy only as a REST backend)

But I would like to explicitly emit events through socket.io and use its room functionality in my controllers, and I'll handle those events in the client side appropriately.

So, my questions are: 1. how do I clean up my existing code in that I don't want realtime models in my app 2. what would I need to do in order to explicitly events from my controllers?

I tried doing the following in after_start.js as shown here: https://github.com/geddy/geddy/wiki/Realtime-and-MVC in "Realtime for existing projects" section, but none of the messages get logged...

```
console.log('Here 1');
geddy.io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Here 2');
    socket.emit('hello', {message: "world"});
    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('Message!');
    });
});
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that the after_start.js was a workaround for the lack of events from the application to know when the server had actually started (so you would know when you could attach Socket.io). Now the `geddy` object in the worker process emits a 'started' event you can use:

http://geddyjs.org/reference#global

So set a listener in your init.js for that event, and set your RT code up in there.